# Formula Rearrangement

Tags: quadratics, fractions, rewriting-systems

Hi StackExchange community,

The formula has this form:

$$ {-7 \pm X \over \sqrt{2} - 3}-3.$$

How can I rewrite this to be more compact ?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by more compact? Can you show an example.

Comment: So the formula is a single fraction ; but I do not mean to multiply $-3$ with ($\sqrt{2} - 3$ but to use the fact that $ - 3$ is both under the fraction and outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rationalize the denominator of the first term:
\begin{align}
\frac{-7\pm X}{\sqrt 2-3}-3 &= \frac{-7\pm X}{\sqrt 2-3} \cdot\frac{\sqrt 2+3}{\sqrt 2+3}-3\\[0.4cm]
&= \frac{-7(\sqrt{2}+3)\pm(\sqrt 2 +3)X}{\sqrt 2^2-3^2}-3\\[0.4cm]
&= \frac{-7(\sqrt 2+3)\pm(\sqrt 2+3)X}{-7}-3\\[0.4cm]
&=\sqrt 2 + 3 \mp \frac{\sqrt 2+3}{7}X - 3\\[0.4cm]
&= \sqrt 2 \mp \frac{\sqrt 2+3}{7}X.
\end{align}
Depending on your preferences, you may or may not find this expression to be "more compact".

Comment: thanks, It is what I was looking for